# How to format layout on GUI in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

So I have my labels and everything added, but I am still having trouble formatting and aligning everything. The calculate button should obviously be centered. I get that using gridbag splits the frame into coordinate system and when one column is larger than the others it will adjust the others and will throw it off(Right?). But I can't understand how to even fix this. And still having trouble aligning everything to the left so it doesn't start towards the center.

[image]

```
 JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());


GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

//0 Column
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    p.add(new JLabel("Mortgage amount:"),gc);


    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy =1;
    p.add(new JLabel("Mortgage term:"),gc);



    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    p.add(new JLabel("Interest rate:"),gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 3;
    p.add(new JLabel("Mortgage start date:"),gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy= 4;
    p.add(new JLabel("Monthly Payments:"),gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 7;
    p.add(new JLabel("Extra payments"),gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 8;
    p.add(new JLabel("Adding: "),gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 9;
    p.add(new JLabel("Adding: "),gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 10;
    p.add(new JLabel("Adding: "),gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 11;
    p.add(new JLabel("Changes paid off date to:"),gc);


    //1 Column
    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    p.add(new JLabel("$"),gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 4;
    p.add(new JLabel("$"),gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 8;
    p.add(new JLabel("$"),gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 9;
    p.add(new JLabel("$"),gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 10;
    p.add(new JLabel("$"),gc);

    //2 column
    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    p.add(new JTextField(8),gc);

    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy =1;
    p.add(new JTextField(8),gc);

    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    p.add(new JTextField(8),gc);

    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 3;
    p.add(new JComboBox(month),gc);

    gc.gridx= 2;
    gc.gridy = 4;
    p.add(new JTextField(8),gc);

    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 8;
    p.add(new JTextField(8),gc);

    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 9;
    p.add(new JTextField(8),gc);

    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 10;
    p.add(new JTextField(8),gc);

    //3 column
    gc.gridx = 3;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    p.add(new JLabel(" years or "),gc);

    gc.gridx = 3;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    p.add(new JLabel(" % per year"),gc);

    gc.gridx = 3;
    gc.gridy = 3;
    p.add(new JComboBox(days),gc);

    gc.gridx = 3;
    gc.gridy = 8;
    p.add(new JLabel("to your monthly mortgage payment"),gc);

    gc.gridx = 3;
    gc.gridy = 9;
    p.add(new JLabel("as an extra yearly mortgage payment every "),gc);

    gc.gridx = 3;
    gc.gridy = 10;
    p.add(new JLabel("as a one-time payment in "),gc);


    //4 column
    gc.gridx = 4;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    p.add(new JTextField(8),gc);

    gc.gridx = 4;
    gc.gridy=3;
    p.add(new JComboBox(years),gc);



    //5 column
    gc.gridx = 5;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    p.add(new JLabel(" months"),gc);

    gc.gridy=5;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    p.add(new JButton("Calculate"),gc);


    add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);





    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

For you labels, try using something like...

```
//...
gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
add(amount,gc);
```

For your fields, try using something like...

```
//...
gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
add(amountfield, gc);
```

`anchor` defines the alignment that a component will have within it's cell, based on the remaining available space.  It can be used to affect the vertical positioning of components as well

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

For example...

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;

        add(new JLabel("Mortage Amount: $"), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Mortage term: "), gbc);
        gbc.gridx += 2;
        add(new JLabel("Years or "), gbc);
        gbc.gridx += 2;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        add(new JLabel(" months "), gbc);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Interest rate: "), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

        add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
        gbc.gridx += 2;
        add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
    }

}
```

Comment: When I use an anchor the positioning just stays center, what causes this?

Comment: Are you using the fill property?

Comment: I am not but how could this affect positioning the JLabel to the top left corner?

Comment: Fill will make the component occupy the entire cell (vertically/horizontally/both), which kind makes the anchor irrelevant